# How can I call second jquery/ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Well, I'm validating my html form with jquery/ajax request. It's process by `add_contact_process.php` page. In this page if **data (family or given name) is exit** then I'm showing a message with a button which value is **Yes and Cancel**.

So
1) If **Yes** button is press I want to call a another jquery/ajax request which save the data to db.
2) If **Cancel** button is press then I want to remove/hide the message.

Can someone suggest me how can I do this ?

**Html form code** :

```
<form id="addcontact">
<table width="450" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  
<tr>
    <td>Family name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="family_name" maxlength="50" placeholder="Family name"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Given name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="given_name"  maxlength="30"placeholder="Given name"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Contact" class="submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>    

<script>
$("#addcontact").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'add_contact_process.php',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',      

    success: function (data) {
        $('#success').html('');
        $('#success').show();
        $.each( data, function( key, value ) {          
        if(key !== 'error' && key !== 'last_id')  {
           $('#success').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');            
           }  
        }); 

        if( ! data.error) {     
            $('#hide').hide();              
             setTimeout(function () {
             $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);        
             var last_id = data.last_id;             
             window.location.href = "../index.php?redcdid="+last_id; 
        },     5000); 
            }

       }
      });
    });
$('#success').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');      
</script>
```

**add_contact_process.php page :**

```
<?php
$family_name = inputvalid(ucfirst($_POST['family_name']));
$given_name = inputvalid(ucfirst($_POST['given_name']));

$exitfname = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT family_name FROM contact_details WHERE family_name = '$family_name'");
$numfname = mysqli_num_rows($exitfname);

$exitgname = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT given_name FROM contact_details WHERE given_name = '$given_name'");
$numgname = mysqli_num_rows($exitgname);

$msg =  array();
$msg['error'] = false;

if(empty($family_name)){
    $msg[] = "<div class='error'>Family name required.</div>";  
    $msg['error'] = true;                           
}

if(strlen($given_name) > 30){
    $msg[] = "<div class='error'>Given name is too big.</div>"; 
    $msg['error'] = true;   
}

// If error is not found            
if($msg['error'] === false){
    if(!empty($family_name) && $numfname >= 1 || !empty($given_name) && $numgname >= 1){
        $msg[] = "<div class='error'>A contact with this name exists. Do you wish to continue adding this new contact?                  
        <input type='submit' name='warning' value='yes' id='yes' class='submit' style='margin:0px;'/>&nbsp;
        <input type='submit' name='warning' value='Cancel' id='cancel' class='submit' style='margin:0px;'/>         
        </div>";
        $msg['error'] = true;           
    }else{      
        $query_2 = "INSERT INTO contact_details (family_name, given_name) VALUES('$family_name', '$given_name')";
        $query_2 =  mysqli_query($link, $query_2);
        $last_id =  mysqli_insert_id($link);

        if($query_2){
            $msg[] = "<div class='success'><strong>Successfully added a new contact</strong>. </div>";          
            $msg['last_id'] = "$last_id";
            $another = "close";
        }else{
            $msg[] = "<div class='success'>Sorry we can not add a new contact details. </div>";
            $msg[] .=  mysqli_error();          
            $another = "close";
        }       
    }   
}       
echo  json_encode($msg);        
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Call Second ajax within success
          <script>
            $("#addcontact").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'add_contact_process.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',      

                success: function (data) {
                    $('#success').html('');
                    $('#success').show();
                    $.each( data, function( key, value ) {          
                    if(key !== 'error' && key !== 'last_id')  {
                       $('#success').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');            
                       }
          /*------------------------------------------------------------------*/  
                       if(confirm('Write your message here')){
                       /* Second ajax after clicking ok on confirm box */
                             $.ajax({
                                url : 'Second URL',
                                method :'POST',
                                data : {'data1':data1}, 
                                success:function(response){
                                        // code after success       
                                },
                                error: function(e){
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });                 
                        }else{
                            $('#success').hide();
                            $('#success').hide();
                        }
        /*----------------------------------------------------------*/

                    }); 

                    if( ! data.error) {     
                        $('#hide').hide();              
                         setTimeout(function () {
                         $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);        
                         var last_id = data.last_id;             
                         window.location.href = "../index.php?redcdid="+last_id; 
                    },     5000); 
                        }

                   }
                  });
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you see my warning message in add_contacct_process.php page ? Here I show Yes Or Cancel Button. So, How it's call second Jquery/Ajax call after press this Yes button ?

Comment: I used your code. If existing data is not found then it's showing confirm message. It's should be show confirm message when `existing data is found and yes button is clicked`

Comment: Send another parameter value in the response,when a duplicate value exist and then in jquery check if that value exist then show confirm box (code given by me) else no confirm box

Answer (score 0):

You should define the second Ajax call in first Ajax call complete method. By default Ajax call is asynchronous, it will start executing the code or statements in success method with out waiting for response from the server. you code should me like this

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'add_contact_process.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',      

            success: function (data) {
               // some code            
                   },

            complete:function () {
           //you second ajax call
            }
```

Comment: You can also make first ajax call synchronous and call the second ajax call in success method.